# How to handle different event sequence in Qt on different operation systems?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, events

I have crossplatform Qt application with custom graphics scene inherited from QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem-based elements on it. 
Both my scene and custom items have context menu so I overload *contextMenuEvent()* method in my classes. Also I overload all the others
mouse event handlers (*mousePressEvent()*, *mouseReleaseEvent()*, *mouseDoubleClickEvent()* and so on). I want to have the same behaviour of
my application on different operating systems. On Windows contextMenuEvent() handler is called after *mouseReleaseEvent()* handler,
but on unix systems first *mouseReleaseEvent()* handler called and only after that *contextMenuEvent()* handler. When I perform right
mouse button click on the item on scene context menu of item is shown and *MyGraphicsScene::focusOutEvent()* is called. 
So event handlers sequence on Windows is:

```
MyGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()
MyGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent()
MyGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent()
MyGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()
MyGraphicsScene::contextMenuEvent()
MyGraphicsItem::contextMenuEvent()
MyGraphicsScene::focusOutEvent()
```

Event handlers sequence on Linux is:

```
MyGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()
MyGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent()
MyGraphicsScene::contextMenuEvent()
MyGraphicsItem::contextMenuEvent()
MyGraphicsScene::focusOutEvent()
```

and *mouseReleaseEvent()* handler is not called.

I perform very essential actions in *mouseReleaseEvent()* methods and have to make some workarounds on Linux or perform additional actions to have the proper behaviour.
As Qt documantation states *mouseReleaseEvent()* handler clears mouse grabber item of the scene so as I understand loosing of *mouseReleaseEvent()* call
cause situation that previous mouse grabber item stay the same and can still get all the events from the scene.

To be fully clear on Linux I get the situation in my app when I call items context menu with right mouse button, click on menu to perform 
some action with item (e.g. rotate it) and after that when I want to move the item it can not be moved at first time 
- I have to perform click on scene and only after that I can move the item. On Windows there is no such problems as menu item is shown in
*contextMenuEvent()* handler which is called after *mouseReleaseEvent()*.

I use Qt 4.6 version in my application.

Do someone deal with such problem before? How can I make the same proper events handling on Linux as it is on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preprocessor. Your compiler should have some predefined macros to identify which OS your code is being compiled for.

```
#ifdef __linux__
// Linux event loop
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
// Windows event loop
#endif
```

Comment: But this does not change the difference between sequence of contextMenuEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent() calls on Linux and Windows. I don't believe that nobody has found such problem before.